# What's a hіt іn halfpіpe?

Tags: terminology, olympics, snowboarding

I've watched a lot of halfpіpe snowboarding іn the past but have no recollectіon of any reference to a "hіt".
This year, іt seems as though іt's standard јargon that any enthusіast should know.

What exactly іs a "hіt"?

[image: TV screenshot of statistics indicating "hіts"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the number of times that the competitor reaches the side and performs a trick.

From [theconversation.com](https://theconversation.com/what-makes-a-winning-halfpipe-snowboarder-like-scotty-james-91833)

> The halfpipe event consists of three runs lasting around 20-30
> seconds, and involves between six and eight “hits” of the pipe. A
> “hit” is an aerial trick (jump, rotation and twist) off the top of the
> pipe.

It does seem like the usage feels "normal" enough that I think many lists of snowboard jargon don't feel the need to include it.  But [REI](https://www.rei.com/learn/expert-advice/snowboarding-glossary.html) placed it in their glossary.

> Hit: The takeoff point on a half-pipe or jump.